# Javascript change the value of a key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some data that looks like this:

```
obj = {
    pref: {
      language: 'English',
    }
};
```

I want to change the value of `language to 'Spanish'`

Comment: `obj.pref.language = ???` What exactly is the issue? Basic syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot notation to access the key and change the value

```js
let obj = {
  pref: {
    language: 'English',
  }
};

obj.pref.language = 'Spanish';

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `obj.pref.language = 'Spanish'` or `obj['pref']['language'] = 'Spanish'`.